# How can I determine via command-line if VBox Guest Additions has been installed?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualbox

In particular, I need to know in order to write a bash script to prompt the user to install VBox Guest Additions on a Ubuntu client if it hasn't already been installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if vboxguest module is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep vboxguest
```

If it is not loaded try to load it:

```
modprobe vboxguest
```

If this command returns non-zero that means Guest Additions are not installed.

I don't have Ubuntu in VB at now but it may be possible to install VboxGuest as an .deb package. In such case just check if package is installed.